# ASP . NET CORE - Identity _LoginPartial.cshtml how to use function from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to use function javascripts inside my _LoginPartial.cshtml file.
Im using ASP .NET CORE IDENTITY.

Why i can't just use simple function there? I want to call  :

```
myFunction()
```

This is my _LoginPartial.cshtml file :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using SildeBar.Areas.Identity.Data
@using SildeBar.Controllers

@inject SignInManager<AppUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AppUser> UserManager




<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-white" title="Manage">Some text : </a>

        </li>

  <script>myFunction()</script>



        <li class="nav-item">
            <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Wyloguj</button>
            </form>
        </li>


        //tutaj dodać ilość TC

        // tutaj dodac stan zł.
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>





@functions{
   
}



<script type="text/javascript">


    function myFunction() {
        return "Some data";
    }


</script>
```

I just  try to call :

```
<script>myFunction()</script>
```

But this text is not displayed.

When i check in browser console there is :

[image]

Please help me with that. I spent a lot of time and can't find solution. I just want to call simple javascript function nothing more... ehh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need call js function in the same script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        return "Some data";
    }
    myFunction();    
</script>
```

But if you want to display the actual return data from this function, what you did(`<script>"Some Data"</script>`) is useless, it will never render in html and it also cannot be used in js as a constant.

If you want to use this return data to did other operation, you could set a constant like below, you can add `console.log(data)` to check if the value has been correctly set:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        return "Some data";
    }
    var data = myFunction();
    console.log(data);    
</script>
```

For example, if you want to render the data to html, you need change like below:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function myFunction() {
        return "Some data";
    }
    var data = myFunction();
    $(".navbar-nav").append('<li><a href="#">' + data +'</a></li>')       
</script>
```

**Note:**

`_LoginPartial.cshtml` rendered as partial view in _Layout.cshtml, so all the references in `_Layout.cshtml` will not be added to `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, you need specific the js reference if you use jquery in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`.

Comment: OK , this good and works . But i can't check now if user is loggin in... How can i check in jquery now if user is logged in? Your exmple add my function always . I wanted just to display this text only for logged in users like you see on my example.

Comment: `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` in your code is used to check if user is logging in. If my answer help you,remember to accept as answer which could also helps community. If still have any other problems, you can post a new thread and share what you did and what you want.